# Set int to a blank in array

Tags: java

i want to set my array to print out a blank space when it meets its condition in an IF statement. This array is a int data type. When i type:

```
item2[2] = ' ';
```

it comes up as 32 when i print it.

Any solutions?

Comment: what is your requirement? can you change your array type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. as your data type is int it will print int representation.

if you cast to `(char)` then it might mess up with actual number to char which isn't needed,

and it is coming 32 because ascii value of `' '` is 32

*Better* to go for array of `String` it will hold both number as well as space . and process them accordingly

Comment: If i change it to a string, my IF statement below will not work. eg:  if (player == item2[x]) player is also a int 

If i change item2 into a string, it will give me an error

Comment: Use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))  and [`StringUtils.isNumeric()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

It's an `int` array. It can only hold integers.

32 is the ASCII value for space, and that's what's being stored when you say `item2[2] = ' ';`.

Answer (score 2):

Ascii value of ' ' (space) is 32 in html, thats why it is echoing 32.

So the char ' ' will be converted to int, which is 32

Answer (score 1):

The character ' ' has that value 32 on int, you need to diference when put a blank or not.
If your space of values is for example only positive values, you can save a -1 where do you what a space and your code could be something like this:

```
for(int i:item2){
  if(i == -1) {
    //Print a blank
  } else {
    //Print the number
  }
}
```

Or you can do a better way, instead of using int, use an array of class Integer, autoboxing will do the automatic convertion and use `null` as "blank value"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store `char` in an array, why not use a `char[]`

```
char[] item2 = new char[10];
item2[2] = ' '; 
System.out.println('|' + items2[2]+'|');
```

prints

```
| |
```